Why don't the Malon dump their waste in black holes?
Why didn't the Malon dump anti-matter waste into black holes instead of all over the place?

Probably because there isn't one nearby. Also they're not the most hospitable of places to visit.

The nearest known black hole in proximity to Earth is Gaia BH1, at 1,560 light years away. So the dispersal of Black holes sufficient distance to be of use may not be economically viable to justify sending a ship on such a long distance journey.
Second, a Black Hole wouldn't solve the problem; thou in the classical sense of physics matter entering a black hole is essentially isolated from conventional spacetime.... energy from black holes is output from various reactions that occur;  Black holes output huge volumes of radiation and some even high energy particle streams so feeding antimatter waste into one probably isn't a wise idea; also the fundamental aspects of warp related waste products isn't addressed in real environmental physics, but subspace permeates beyond conventional distance so radiation saturated in subspace related energies can travel Faster-than-light. So an energetic reaction of unstable waste products may have external effects that can affect regions of space in a damaging fashion, potentially jeopardize the ship dumping the waste or whole regions of space.

That sounds like a good reason, I kind of wish it was addressed in the show. Kind of like how the Malon couldn't learn to recycle their waste the way EVERY civilization seems able to, even in the 22 century. The first Malon said it would put him out of business but certainly their government or other business savoy Malon would ask other people what they do with their waste and form a profitable business doing it. I think it should have been the way the Malon generate anti-matter energy made the method unusable. Maybe they don't use dilithium or maybe they use elements heavier than Deuterium.
